# Remove all occurrences of character x from a given string recursively

Tags: c++, c

I have written two solutions to this problem one with the head recursion and the other with the tail recursion. One with the head recursion passes all the test cases but the solution with tail recursion is missing one case. I am not able to figure out which case I am missing. Can someone please help me here?

One with head recursion

```
void removeX(char input[]) {
    if (input[0] == '\0')
        return;

    removeX(input+1);

    if (input[0] == 'x') {
        strcpy(input, input+1);
        removeX(input);
    }

}
```

One with tail recursion

```
void removeX(char input[]) {
    if (input[0] == '\0')
        return;

    if (input[0] == 'x') {
        strcpy(input, input+1);
        removeX(input);
    }

    removeX(input+1);
}
```

P.S.
The program is supposed to remove all character 'x' from the input string.

Example test cases:

input  -----------------> output

xxxxxss ----------------> ss

aaaxxx  ----------------> aaa

Now these are simple test cases in which both the solutions with head and tail recurison gives correct answers. But, there are some test cases for which tail recursion fails and I am trying to figure out in what are those cases and why does it fail.

Comment: what test cases? Please post a [mcve] and tag only the language you are using

Comment: Do you need a solution in C or C++? They both are different languages. Also, aren't both code samples the same?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have updated the code for head recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions have undefined behavior because the arrays passed to `strcpy` should not overlap: change `strcpy(input, input+1);` to

```
memmove(input, input + 1, strlen(input + 1) + 1);
```

Furthermore, both functions have the same code, which is not tail recursion. They recurse twice on each occurrence of `x`, which is either redundant or incorrect if the last character in the string is an `x`.

Here is a modified version with tail recursion:

```
void removeX(char *input) {
    if (input[0] == '\0')
        return;

    if (input[0] == 'x') {
        memmove(input, input + 1, strlen(input + 1) + 1);
        removeX(input);
    } else {
        removeX(input + 1);
    }
}
```

Using recursion for this type of problem is not idiomatic in C. A simple loop is preferred, with linear time complexity instead of potential quadratic time for strings with long sequences of `x`:

```
void removeX(char *input) {
    char *p = input;
    while ((*p = *input++) != '\0') {
        if (*p != 'x')
            p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think time complexitty of that recursive algorithm is 0(n^3), where n is the length of string. Because `strlen()` -> 0(n), `memmove()` -> O(n) and `removeX()` -> O(n). That's really not a well techinque to remove a character from a string. I don't know what's OP's aim for that inefficient function.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: no, `strlen()` and `memmove()` times are added, not multiplied, so the overall time complexity for long strings of `x` is still O(n*n), which is still much less efficient than the classic and idiomatic 2 finger approach.

Comment: O(n^2) >>> O(n) linear one

Comment: In your linear approach solution parameter `input` wasn't changed

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: the `input` pointer is incremented in `(*p = *input++)` and the array is modified via `*p`.

Comment: Ooh yes p is actually input, as = operator copies every data to second pointer and modifying the second one will automatically change the first one (strtok does that too)

Comment: `p` is the output pointer. They both point to the same array but `p` is only incremented if the byte copied is not an `x`.

Comment: Yup, that's some formal definition to say that (C is small yet full of surprises for anyone)